# How can I make a 3-D cube from 6 images in my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es, core-animation

I'm new to iPhone programming. I have 6 PNGs that represent all sides of my classroom from the inside. I would like to make them into a single 3-D cube that you would view from the inside, with the ability to look around this cube by moving your finger.

How would I go about implementing something like this?  I found Core Animation's CATransform3D and a little about textures in OpenGL, but I'm not sure what to use for my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for something called a [Skybox](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Skybox).  The coding for this is well understood and you shouldn't have any difficulty finding example OpenGL code to use.  [Here](http://www.gpwiki.org/index.php/Sky_Box) is as good a place to start as any, but just Google 'OpenGL Skybox' for lots of examples.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty arbitrary question but I think I can help, Pangea software has some tools to help do this and some other information related to it:

http://www.pangeasoft.net/pano/index.html

The owner is a pretty nice guy and can probably help you out with some integration or source code.