# How to create Cube 3D with 6 faces with 6 UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have 6 'UIView's with different components in each of them. I want to show them as 3D Cube look, i.e. each UIView will be basically a face of the cube. User will slide on faces of cube to view all 6 faces, and do basic operation on each face.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737703/how-can-i-make-a-3-d-cube-from-6-images-in-my-iphone-application

Comment: They are related by methodology, but in my case i want to place any standard UIControl in a face of the cube, not only image.